# Submitting Type of Object to Method

Tags: c++

### Intro

I have a method which performs k-fold-cross-validation and needs for this purpose a graph, a link predictor and an evaluator.
So the class could look like this:

```
KFoldCrossValidator {    
  public:
    KFoldCrossValidator(const Graph& G, LinkPredictor* lp, Evaluator e);
    double crossValidate(unsigned int k);
}
```

where a typical LinkPredictor looks like the following:

```
SpecialLinkPredictor : public LinkPredictor {
  public:
    SpecialLinkPredictor(const Graph& G, double alpha, double beta);
    double run(node u, node v);
}
```

where `alpha` and `beta` are parameters for the predictor.

### Problem

The `crossValidate`-method splits the given Graph `G` into `k` subgraphs and then (among other things) executes the `run`-method from the LinkPredictor for every edge in all the subgraphs.

The problem is that I have to create a new LinkPredictor-instance for every subgraph as I have to submit the respective subgraph in the constructor of the LinkPredictor. This is not possible if I just submit a pointer to a LinkPredictor-object.

A possible solution to this problem could be the submission of an enum indicating the LinkPredictor that should be used as well as some sort of vector which holds all the arguments (alpha, beta, ...) for the instantiation. I think that's a very bad idea.

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to reset the `Graph` associated with the `LinkPredictor`. Call the function to set the `Graph` on the passed in `LinkPredictor` instead of constructing a new `LinkPredictor` for each sub-graph.

Comment: Unfortunately the graph gets submitted as a const reference so I can't simply change the reference later on. Submitting the graph by value is not possible under the given circumstances.

Comment: Can you store a `const*` to the `Graph` instead of a `const&`?

Comment: I remodelled some of the classes and I think using a const* is the best idea. Thank you for you help :)